# Exclusion plots

Tags: experimental-physics, dark-matter, wimps

I am having issues in reading exclusion plots like the one in the picture below (It is a plot regarding WIMP searches). What does the lines from various experiments (such as CRESST or LUX) mean? I don't understand if the line excludes the region above or below. I know that the closed lines are regions where something has been seen (the DAMA/LIBRA regions have seen annual modulation), so those closed regions mean that it is possible to have a WIMP with a mass of approximately 50 GeV and with a X-section of approximately $10^{-3}$ pb. But I don't understand if the CRESST line (for example) means  that if a WIMP had a mass of 30 GeV, then the cross section cannot be higher or lower than $10^{-5}$ pb.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: Does my answer here [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410117/exclusion-limits-on-particle-dark-matter/613205#613205] answer your question too?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Cross sections above the lines are ruled out.

The vertical axis on this plot is "cross section", which is a measure for the interaction probability. Higher cross sections mean higher interaction probability.  Experiments search for interactions, and if they don't find anything significant, they rule out that dark matter interacts more often than what they were sensitive to. Thus, they rule out high cross sections, whereas low cross sections are still allowed.

Comment: So only NEWS-G is compatible with DAMA/LIBRA, right?

Comment: That is correct. All other experiments have ruled out DAMA/LIBRA over and over again, and by huge margins. That's a discussion on its own, but there is certainly no dark matter to be found in DAMA/LIBRA data.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer