# How To Interpret Cross-Section vs. WIMP Mass Graph?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, scattering-cross-section, wimps

I'm a bit confused about how to interpret experimental data when it comes to dark matter. For example, in this figure from the XENON1T experiment, is it correct in saying that the upper bound for the cross-section of a WIMP-nucleon interaction is 10^-46 cm^2 for a WIMP mass of about 20 GeV/c^2? If DM particles have not been directly detected, how do they arrive at these conclusions?

Any help is much appreciated as particle physics is not my forte!

[image]

Comment: What they are saying is that if dark matter consisted of a particle with that mass and cross section, they *would* have seen it in their data (with some high probability). Since they did not see evidence of dark matter, dark matter can't have those properties (with a high probability). How they know they would have seen the signal is where all of the "good stuff" is -- that requires understanding their detector very well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclusion limits on particle dark matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410117/exclusion-limits-on-particle-dark-matter)

Comment: And yes, Andrew's comment is correct.